# Software/Plugin that tracks website actions

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, testing, scripting

We are currently moving a lot of our code to use the api we've developed instead of making sql calls from our php.  There will be a lot of functionality to test once this happens.  I was wondering if you know of a good plugin or software to use to track and replicate and action (such as registering a user, the logging in, posting a comment, etc).  I know there is software like selenium, but I've heard that it would be more of a hassle to setup than it's worth (for what we need it for).

I basically want to create a script of my actions on our stable build, then run that script on the build that is using our newly implemented api build that uses a different database, then come the two databases to make sure they have the same data.

Any suggestions would be great.  There has to be a chrome plugin or something, but I haven't been be able to find it after a few hours of searching.

Answer (score 1):

If these are web service calls to your API, you can use curl (on the command line or within PHP) or even Guzzle as it's just an HTTP Client for communicating with web services. What you are describing is testing your app, which is common. There is nothing trivial or easy about full test coverage so prepare to spend some time setting this up and working out the kinks.